# How to set log4j.properties in Eclipse?

Tags: java, log4j, jms, appender

I'm trying to run [this example](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html), but I have some problems with configuration.

I copied `log4j-jms.properties`, `jndi.properties`, `Log4jJMSAppenderExample.java`

```
ProjectJMS
|
\_ src
|   \_ Log4jJMSAppenderExample.java
|   \_ jndi.propeties
\_ log4j-jms.properties
```

and run `activemq` in my console.

When I ran my example I got

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.`PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j-jms.properties");`
```

so I added

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j-jms.properties");
```

Now I can see logs in Eclipse console, but still with this warning

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2012-08-13 10:21:44,741 INFO  Log4jJMSAppenderExample - Test log
Received log [INFO]: Test log
```

and in console with `activemq` I got

```
 WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:2005 failed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Why am I getting these warnings?

1. Are my imports wrong?

   ```
   import javax.jms.Connection;
   import javax.jms.Message;
   import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
   import javax.jms.MessageListener;
   import javax.jms.Session;

   import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
   import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage;
   import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
   import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
   import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
   ```
2. Are my files in wrong place?
3. How to set configuration file in Eclipse? Without using `PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j-jms.properties");`? There is no line like this in example I follow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `log4j.properties` should reside inside the `src` folder. That way, Log4J will configure itself automatically, without you needing to write code.

Comment: I moved this file and in VM arguments added `-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-jms.properties`. Works now, thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a `log4j-jms.properties`? You don't need this at all. `log4j.properties` is the system default configuration property for Log4J.

Comment: I've made a mistake in my question. I named my file `log4j-jms.properties`, there is no `log4j.properties`. I can rename it, but it works OK.

Comment: Still, you don't need to create another properties file if the system-wide Log4J default properties work.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi - Can you please help me with a related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278607/using-simple-log4j-properties-in-my-java-code

Answer (score 2):

1. There is nothing about imports;
2. It's not about the file place, as you see this message "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger...", so please check the content of your log4j configuration file. Here's a demo:

   log4j.rootLogger=INFO, myConsoleAppender
   log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
   log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
3. The default log4j configuration file is "log4j.properties", and as someone had said it should be place in the `src` folder.

Comment: As I've said. I copied `log4j.properties` from tutorial, so it works OK. After adding additional argument to VM, I receive no warnings.

Answer (score 1):

According to your project structure, there is no log4j-jms.properties.There is log4j.properties. So change your log4j properties file name.