# Where is log4j-jms.properties in Linux?

Tags: eclipse, log4j, jasper-reports, jms

I'm trying to compile a simple Java application with Swing. It shows a jList from a sql query. That works.

I have a button to export a selection to a report, using a .jrmxl I've already did. That file works with the connection.

The problem is I need to include Jasperreports funcionality.

I got the message

> log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j-jms.properties].
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j-jms.properties (No such file or > directory)

The closest answered question I found was this:

[How to set log4j.properties in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930606/how-to-set-log4j-properties-in-eclipse)

But **I can't find where *log4j-jms.properties* is**.

I'm using Xubuntu 11.04 and Eclipse 3.7.2.

Any help?

Comment: I do not understand, why is the log4j-jms.properties being looked for in the first place ? Is JMS used by Jasper-reports ?

Comment: @AshutoshJindal No, it does not used

Comment: I got "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger" when trying to use jasperreports. I found that including the line "PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j-jms.properties");" that message disappeared, but then I got this new problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the following in a file called `log4j-jms.properties` in the root of your `src` folder :

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=FATAL


#configuring the JMS appender
log4j.appender.JMS=org.apache.log4j.net.JMSAppender
```

Optionally, try creating the same file as above with no contents ?

Another suggestion : I would suggest setting an **[exception breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066199/eclipse-break-when-exception-is-thrown)** for  `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. Then when it is hit, you can see the call trace in the debug view and just before where the exception break point is hit, you can see the path where `log4j-jms.properties` is being looked for.