# Using simple Log4j.properties in my java code

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I made a simple `Hibernate 3.1` java code (in eclipse) which successfully creates a table in a database. I have `slfj-api-1.6.0.jar` and `slfj-simple-1.6.0.jar` in my project. But, I don't see any `Log4j` logging warnings or messages in the console output. How do I make log4j log things to my console ?

My tutorial says that one of the lines I should get in the console is -

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type = debug
```

I saw a couple of posts online which tell me to place a `Log4j.properties` file in my java project, either in `src` folder, or make a `resources` folder inside `src` and put it there. I found one `Log4j.properties` in my computer and placed it in the `resources` folder. I am not sure if I should use the settings in that file or how to edit this file as per my requirement. How do I do this correctly ?

**EDIT -**

The `log4j.properties` file -

```
### Direct log messages to stdout ###
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

### set log levels - ###
log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout log4j.logger.org.hibernate.info

### log JDBC bind parameters ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=debug

###log schema export/update ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=debug
```

Thanks.

Comment: If memory serves me correctly, `hibernate.cfg.xml` must be in a root folder as well, i.e., a `src` folder.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi - Thanks. I just figured out why my hibernate config file was not being loaded - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736594/location-of-hibernate-cfg-xml-in-project/23280572#23280572v Anyway, that is besides the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the file name **must** be in lowercase. The `Log4j.properties` file is wrong, it's `log4j.properties`. This must be put in the root folder of your project (in most cases the `src` folder).

Secondly, you need to download the log4j jar file if you want to use SLF4J bridge with log4j. Download the latest library that you require from [Apache Logging Services](http://logging.apache.org/). Don't forget that there are 2 versions of Apache Log4J, so I suggest you try version 1.x first.

Good luck!

Comment: I put it inside `resources` folder which is inside `src` folder. I'll add my logger.properties file.

Comment: It should be only in `src` folder. That's how Log4J is configured.

Comment: According to @AlexR in this post, you can put it in `src` or in any folder inside `src` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081316/where-is-the-correct-location-to-put-log4j-properties-in-an-eclipse-project

Comment: I added `log4j 1.2 jar` to my `lib` folder and now I at least get the WARN messages. I tried to add the `log4j.properties` file to my `src` folder also and Log4j gives me the error - `ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.stdout log4j.logger.org.hibernate.info`

Comment: UPDATE - I am using `Eclipse` to do a `hibernate` example. I DON'T get the WARN messages when I keep `log4j.properties` inside the `src` folder. But, when I keep it under `src/resources` folder, then I get the warning. Why does this happen and how do I make eclipse refer to the correct folder ?

Comment: As I said earlier, Log4J looks for `log4j.properties` on the root folder of your project. If you want to add it to your `resources` folder, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390521/change-location-of-log4j-properties/7390644#7390644).

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that the file should be called `log4j.properties` and should be placed in the root of your src or resource folder (by default at least) ... you seem to be calling it `Log4j.properties`

I also think that you are missing the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The resources folder is only an option if you identify it as a source folder on the project properties!java build path!source tab.

Slf4j does not use log4j to write to the logs unless you include the slf4j-log4j[version].jar (for example, slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar) jar in your project.  If you include this jar, then you must not include the slfj-simple-1.6.0.jar jar in your project.

Here is a link to the [slf4j online manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)

Comment: I included the slf4j-simple on purpose. A while ago, I got a runtime exception class not found. I searched google and and found that adding slf4j-simple fixes the problem. Honestly, I don't know what I am really doing. Just trying to make learn hibernate.